# Java byte value not correct

Tags: java

I have this hex value 93 which in decimal value should be 147. Since this number is less than 255, it is representable in a byte.

In java I did this

```
System.out.println((new Integer(1)).byteValue()); //prints 1
System.out.println((new Integer(147)).byteValue()); //prints -109!!! WHY?
```

What am I not understanding? with integer of 147 instead of printing 147 it prints -109...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because byte is in the range -128:127 ([see here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)). When you call `byteValue()` you can't get anything out of that range, so it overflows (and starts from the lowest value)

Comment: And Java doesn't have unsigned datatypes.

Comment: @TimCooper Yes it does: `char` is an unsigned `short`

Answer (score 6):

A `byte` in Java is *signed*, therefore it represents the values in the range of -128 to 127, as opposed to the unsigned alternative in other languages in the range of 0 to 255. All of Java's integer types are signed, excluding `char` since since it's used to hold 16-bit Unicode values from 0 to 65535.

The value 147 stored as a byte is represented in binary as:

```
10010011
```

Since according to the Oracle docs a `byte` is: *"an 8-bit signed **two's complement** integer"*, the signed value becomes:

```
= -2^7 + 2^4 + 2^1 + 2^0
= -128 + 16 + 2 + 1
= -109
```

Comment: ... except `char` is an unsigned `short`

Comment: @Bohemian yeah you're right it's an unsigned 16-bit type for holding Unicode. I didn't explain myself well when I put " *integer types* are signed..." since `char` obviously is an integer type. I'll fix that, thanks.