# Store signed value in Byte

Tags: java, primitive

I was trying to store byte value in a variable and trying to perform some logic based upon this calculation.

```
byte mByteValue = -129;   // Holding byte value
```

Problem is I am always getting value 127, due to which my logic fails everytime.

Any specific reason behind this, why its behaving strange in my case?

Comment: You need to read about integer overflow and min/max values of byte.

Comment: byte's can only store -128 to 127

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#MIN_VALUE

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java byte value not correct](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8015796/java-byte-value-not-correct)

Answer (score 3):

A `byte` in java is a *signed* 8-bit value. 8 bits gives you 256 possible values, but since a `byte` is *signed* and can represent positive *and* negative values, those 256 values must be roughly split in half across the possible positive and negative values. So you can't store negative values past *-128*; in particular don't expect to be able to store `-256`.

What you're actually observing when your byte has the value `127` is known as *overflow* (see [this wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_overflow))

If you need to manipulate values outside this range, as in your example code, or e.g. an *unsigned* byte, at some point you'll need to make use of a wider integer type, like `short`.

The standard libraries provide these limits as `Byte.MIN_VALUE` and `Byte.MAX_VALUE` (docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#MIN_VALUE) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#MAX_VALUE)).

Answer (score 0):

The range of `byte` is from -128 to 127. You can not store any value beyond these range.

This is because `byte` is 8 bits. So the maximum positive number stored at byte is -

```
2^7 -1 = 127. // since the first bit is sing bit; 0 for positive
```

And minimum negative number stored at byte is-

```
2^7 = -128 //since the first bit is sign bit; 1 for negative.
```

And if you use `unsigned` byte the it would be 255.

Comment: other way around, -128 to 127

Comment: Thanks, @Hunter McMillen. It was a typo I have fixed it.

Comment: That's seems to be quite helpful, storing this in sort or int solve the issue. Meanwhile question seems to be valid, there in no point of down voting it for a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

To correctly convert a byte to an int use `mByteValue & 0xFF`. You can read more about the `Two's complement` here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement.